# Node server method not firing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http

I have the following web service that we have created.

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {  
const user = req.body;   

// registerSchema.validate(user, registerSchema, (err, result) => {
//     if (err)
//         res.status(500).end(err.message);
// });

findUserByEmail(user.email, (err, userFeedback) => {
    console.log('Fired.');
    if (userFeedback)
        res.status(500).end(JSON.stringify("User already exists"));
});

const passwordPromise = util.promisify(bcrypt.hashSync);
const pass = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password);

createUser(user.name, user.email, pass, [], (err) => {
    if (err)
        res.status(418).end(JSON.stringify("Failed to create user."));
});

res.status(200).end(JSON.stringify("Signup successful."));
});
```

We are using this to register a user. Here are the methods we are calling in this part of the web service.

```
function createUser (userName, userEmail, userPass, dev, cb) {
var mg = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mg.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db){
    var dbo = db.db(myDB);
    var user = { name: userName, 
                 email: userEmail,
                 password: userPass,
                 devices: dev };

    var insert = util.promisify(dbo.collection("Users").insertOne);

    dbo.collection("Users").insertOne(user, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`${user.name} has been added.`);
        db.close();
        sendEmail(userEmail, 
                  'The CRUST Company welcomes you!',
                  'Thank you for signing up for our services!' );
    });
});
}

 //See if a user exists
function findUserByEmail (userEmail) {
var mg = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mg.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, 
function(err, db){
    var dbo = db.db(myDB);
    var query = { email : userEmail };

    var find = util.promisify(dbo.collection("Users").find);
    return dbo.collection("Users").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.close();
    });
});
}
```

The createUser seems to be working fine but the FindUserByEmail is not firing at all. We even tried console.log within the method and got no response. Any ideas on why this method may not be firing? Thx

Comment: What does "is not firing" mean?  What exactly happens?  What do you observe?  Are you logging all possible errors?  It does not appear like you are doing anything with the `result` value in the callback for the `.find()` operation.

Comment: I mean that the method is not executing at all

Comment: What method is not executing at all?  Come on here.  Be SPECIFIC about exactly what your code does.  To exactly which line does it execute?  Where do you first notice a problem?  We can't debug this ourselves so if you want our help, you have to be the eyes and tell us EXACTLY what is happening so we can develop theories for why.  This question contains far too little information for us to help you as it is.  It may start accumulating downvotes and get closed because of insufficient information.  As you may be new here, stackoverflow requires thorough and clear questions or they get closed.

Comment: Also, please indent your code properly in the question to make it readable.

Comment: I told you its the finduserbyemail function that is not executing at all

Comment: CreateUser executes fine but the finduserbyemail does not activate at all

Comment: For the future, your terminology has been confusing to me.  The `findUserByEmail()` function gets called just fine.  If you put a `console.log("running findUserByEmail()");` on the first line of that function, it would output to the console.  It's the callback function that you pass it that doesn't get called.  So, the function is indeed executing.  And "activating" is not a Javascript term so nobody knows what you mean by that.  You need to describe exactly which lines of code are or aren't executing rather than using terms with no specific definition.

Comment: I did try putting the console log in and it showed nothing that is what was confusing me as well

Answer (score 0):

Your calling code passes `findUserByEmail()` a callback function:

```
findUserByEmail(user.email, (err, userFeedback) => {
    console.log('Fired.');
    if (userFeedback)
        res.status(500).end(JSON.stringify("User already exists"));
});
```

But, your actual implementation of that function doesn't accept a callback and thus never calls it so of course the callback you pass never gets called.

---

Also, there are multiple asynchronous design problems.  You are treating asynchronous operations like they are blocking.  They are not.  You must continue the flow of your code INSIDE the callback function, not after the function call which you do correctly inside of `findUserByEmail()` but do not do correctly in your request handler where you call it.

---

Also, `createUser()` declares a callback as an argument, but never calls it so the callback you pass to `createUser()` will also never get called.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is my first time using javascript so i am unsure about the imp,lementations. Have a good day

Comment: @SteveRogers - If this answered your question, the convention here is that you can indicate that to the rest of the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here which can eventually lead to extra privileges on the site.